# File name convention in rspec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, naming-conventions, rspec2

I noticed in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Hartl that he uses rails generate to create the rspec file. For example,

```
rails generate integration_test static_pages
```

creates the file `static_pages_spec.rb`. My question is, is there a naming convention for the name of the file?

Also, is there a naming convention for the text between `describe` and `do`? I'm aware that writing something like `/people/new` will set up the render automatically when testing a view so all I need to do is write `render`, but what other naming conventions exist out there in rspec?